# RAID failure - physical defect in drive?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, raid

we're using a RAID 1 on a raspberry pi and it seems (from the output of /proc/mdstat) that one of the devices is gone:

```
mschnick@pi3:~ $ sudo cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1](F) sda1[2]
      976629760 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 8/8 pages [32KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

However, the "broken" /failed device is present in both fdisk and lsusb.
After checking on smartctl, it seems to be intact there, as well.

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status not supported: Incomplete response, ATA output registers    missing
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.


SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE       UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       2988
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       25163
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   077   077   000    Old_age   Always       -       9300
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   253   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   085   085   000    Old_age   Always       -       152088
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       33 (Min/Max 22/50)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4101
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       3439
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       178
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
```

So, given all the information, it seems that the drive is available, yet mdadm fails to accept the drive.

Searching the net for useful information was not successful, mostly because I cannot express the problem in concise words.

Which next steps should I take?
Do I have to replace the drive or is the problem somewhere else?

I'm grateful for any advice pointing into the right direction.

Best regards
Michael

Comment: You most likely have a drive which is OK, but not designed for RAID - which took too long to respond and was kicked from the array.  What model drive is it?

Comment: makes me wonder as the drive was running nicely for some years now. there were a couple of subsequent power outages in the entire house though, due to issues with the earth leakage power breaker ... different story. When I started reconstructing, this was the result.

As for the drive type:  TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100, 2.5" HDD, sold with a USB-enclosure.